# Handling Intervals

Tags: algorithm

How to find the number of intervals that fall's in the given range . for example
Let me explain the question suppose there are Range [1,10] and the provided intervals are (1,3),(1,8),(2,4),(2,5),(2,3),(3,9),(3,8),(3,6) and ask to find out the number of intervals that fall'a between the ranges [1,5] the answer is 4. These are four [(1,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,3)] intervals that fall's in the range [1,5]. same as if there are Range[1,N] and i provide you the intervals ,then how to find out that how many intervals are in the given range.what is the best complexity to this task for every query ?

Answer (score 2):

O(n). You can't do any better. At the very least, you have to answer that every single interval is valid for a query, which is O(n). You can get O(n) by simply iterating through the list to test if query_min <= interval_min && query_max <= interval_max

Comment: Well, you could do better via some form of indexing, but it would be a time-memory trade off.